# WCF: The contract 'X' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract

Tags: c#, wcf

This error message shows when I try run my WCF service in VS, and I'm trying to figure out what it's actually referring to by 'client configuration' and 'service contract':

*The contract 'IMyService' in client configuration does not match the name in service contract*

I assume the **service contract** part refers to this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/yyy", ConfigurationName = "IMyService")]
public interface IMyService
{
    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation MyService is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Task))]
    SendResponse Request(SendRequest request);
}
```

Any ideas what the **client configuration** refers to?

Edit: In my web.config I have this section for system.serviceModel:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyServiceBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="XXX.YYY.MyService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding" name="MyServiceSendHttps"
          contract="IMyService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: how about `app.config`

Comment: Is there some client section I should add?

Comment: See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See app.config file in your project.
If you don't configure  client programmatically, then app.config file must include a node of configuration of clients.

Update:
Your first code snippet includes this line:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/yyy", ConfigurationName = "IMyService")]`.
```

In documentation for "ConfigurationName" property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.configurationname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
we can read:

> The name used to locate the service element in an application configuration file. The default is the **name of the service implementation class.**

So, we have:
name of the service implementation class are "XXX.YYY.MyService", and (in second code snippet) we see " <service name="XXX.YYY.MyService"> " but property's ConfigurationName value is "IMyService".

If you just remove 'ConfigurationName = "IMyService" ' from line

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/yyy", ConfigurationName = "IMyService")]
```

like this:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/yyy")]
```

that should fix the issue.

Comment: Added web.config to question - is there an example of client config in the config file?

Comment: Hmm that didn't quite work but when I took it all out and just used [ServiceContract] with [OperationContract] on the method, it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and I spent many hours looking for the solution. Then I found [this article](https://shishkin.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/wcf-actions-asterisk-and-metadata/) about generated code by the WCF tool svcutil.exe.

Generated C# code is not guaranteed to be also suitable for a service-side contract. In my case the problem was in ReplyAction = "*" (which I see also in the question). According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.replyaction.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-Ixm1bt6ysX5YCRKGW9KkSA&tduid=(e81b02381e87b0ab85eef3840ecc4844)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-Ixm1bt6ysX5YCRKGW9KkSA)()):

> Specifying an asterisk in the service instructs WCF not to add a reply
>   action to the message, which is useful if you are programming against
>   messages directly.

After changing

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
```

to

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "")]
```

was the problem solved.